# overlay center position not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tools

I use jQuery Tools for overlay effects.
This will sound very strange but when overlay is opened the first time, its not centered as expected but its positioned all the way to the left.
If I close the link and open it again, this time its centered??
No idea what is going on here...

```
$(function() {
        $("a[rel]").overlay({ 
            mask: '#000',
            top: 'center', 
            left: 'center',
            onBeforeLoad: function() {
                // grab wrapper element inside content
                var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                // load the page specified in the trigger
                wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"), function(){initialize();});
            }
        });
    }); 
<a href="default.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckinMap" rel="#overlay">clik to map</a>
<!-- overlayed element -->
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
  <!-- the external content is loaded inside this tag -->
  <div class="contentWrap"></div>
</div>
<style>
  /* use a semi-transparent image for the overlay */
  #overlay {
    background-image:url(/media/img/overlay/transparent.png);
    color:#efefef;
    height:450px;
  }
  /* container for external content. uses vertical scrollbar, if needed */
  div.contentWrap {
    height:400px;
    width:960px;
    background: #FFF;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: what is jsfiddle, never heard of it before?

Comment: I dont get an error at jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You just need make your `#overlay` position: relative and add a set width:

```
#overlay {
    position:relative;
    width:480px;
}
```

The width can be whatever you want, but it does need a width.